# how to extract a specific key value pair from a dict with a nested list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following data structure whereby I would like to extract a given key: value pair by searching for the specific value. Use Case: I need to extract u'LOB_B': u'mcsmsg.example.net' from the dict.

```
{u'status': u'successful',
 u'availableFqdnList': [
     {u'LOB_A': u'pcload.us.example.net'},
     {u'LOB_B': u'mcsmsg.example.net'},
     {u'LOB_B': u'gtxd.example.net'},
     {u'LOB_B': u'diamond.example.net'}]}

for key, value in my_dict.values():
    if value == 'mcsmsg.example.net':
        print("Print key value pairs for available FQDN list")
        print key, "=", value
```

Error = for key, value in my_dict.values():
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: You dictionary is invalid. It must not contain duplicate keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a simple to understand way of getting this done

```
d = {u'status': u'successful', 
        u'availableFqdnList': [{u'LOB_A': u'pcload.us.example.net'}, 
                               {u'LOB_B': u'mcsmsg.example.net'}, 
                               {u'LOB_B': u'gtxd.example.net'}, 
                               {u'LOB_B': u'diamond.example.net'}]}

for val in d['availableFqdnList']:
    if val.values()[0] == "mcsmsg.example.net":
        print("%s=%s" %(val.keys()[0], val.values()[0]))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Geeze seems so simple after seeing the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think values() is the function you want.

Probably you want items() instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using python2, you can using `iteritems()`

Or for python3, it's `items()`

They will iter the key, value in the dictionary for you.

```
dic = {'a':1,'b':2}

for key,value in dic.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

it will return

```
a
1

b
2
```